# INSERTAR REGISTRO MYSQL SI NO EXISTE Y SI EXISTE REEMPLAZAR CANTIDAD+NUEVA CANTIDAD

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando ver en una sola consulta mysql si se puede insertar un registro mientras no exista el id_producto_canal y si existiese entonces reemplazar solo el campo "cantidad" sumando la cantidad actual del registro mas la nueva cantidad.

Estoy provando con esto pero no me funciona:

```
$qq = "REPLACE INTO productos_canal
SET 
id_producto_canal = ".$data["id_producto"].$data["canal"].",
id_producto = ".$data["id_producto"].",
id_canal = ".$data["canal"].",
unidades = unidades+".$data["unidades"];

$bd->query($qq);
```

el codigo lo puse asi para mayor legibilidad en la practica uso algo mas seguro y mas organizado

Notas:

- Todos las variables $data[...] estan validas y si existen lo que no me funciona es `"unidades = unidades+$data["unidades"]` (tal cual se haria con UPDATE)
- Para evitarme problemas deberia consultar primero si existe el registro y luego con otra consulta usar insert o update segun sea necesario pero quisiera ver si en una consulta puedo hacer lo mismo

Comment: Si `id_producto_canal` es llave primaria o única puedes usar [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la mejor opción es hacerlo como indicas:

```
<?php
$bd=new mysqli('localhost','root','','_so');
$data=[
    'id_producto'=>1,
    'id_canal'=>1,
    'unidades'=>3,
];
$rs=$bd->query("
    SELECT * FROM productos_canal
      WHERE id_producto=".($data["id_producto"]*1).";
");
if($rs->num_rows)
    $bd->query("
        UPDATE productos_canal SET
          id_canal = ".($data["id_canal"]*1).",
          id_producto_canal = '".$data["id_producto"].$data["id_canal"]."',
          unidades = unidades+".($data["unidades"]*1)."
          WHERE id_producto=".($data["id_producto"]*1).";
    ");
else 
    $bd->query("
        INSERT INTO productos_canal (
            id_producto, id_canal, id_producto_canal, unidades
          ) VALUES (
          ".($data["id_producto"]*1).",
          ".($data["id_canal"]*1).",
          ".($data["id_producto"]*1).($data["id_canal"]*1).",
          ".($data["unidades"]*1)."
          );
    ");
```

Si el `UPDATE` realizara un `INSERT` cada vez que le pasáramos algo que no existiera en el `WHERE`, yo creo nos pasaríamos aún más tiempo limpiando datos.

Tal vez, para ahorrarte la consulta previa, podrías intentar hacer el `UPDATE` y, si no modifica nada, lanzarte a por el `INSERT`:

```
<?php
$bd=new mysqli('localhost','root','','_so');
$data=[
    'id_producto'=>2,
    'id_canal'=>1,
    'unidades'=>3,
];
$bd->query("
    UPDATE productos_canal SET
      id_canal = ".($data["id_canal"]*1).",
      id_producto_canal = '".$data["id_producto"].$data["id_canal"]."',
      unidades = unidades+".($data["unidades"]*1)."
      WHERE id_producto=".($data["id_producto"]*1).";
");
if(!$bd->affected_rows)
    $bd->query("
        INSERT INTO productos_canal (
            id_producto, id_canal, id_producto_canal, unidades
          ) VALUES (
          ".($data["id_producto"]*1).",
          ".($data["id_canal"]*1).",
          ".($data["id_producto"]*1).($data["id_canal"]*1).",
          ".($data["unidades"]*1)."
          );
    ");
```

Es muy importante que el campo `id_producto` sea al menos `UNIQUE` para que no inserte un duplicado.

Aporto el dataset para las pruebas:

```
CREATE TABLE productos_canal(
  id_producto int PRIMARY KEY,
  id_canal int,
  id_producto_canal varchar(15),
  unidades int
  );
```

En cualquier caso, que tengas ya el `id_producto` es un poco extraño, ¿no será mejor que dejes ese campo como autonumérico y crees otro campo `referencia` con una clave única? Simplemente por no depender de referencias externas cuando necesites combinar tablas.